# Microsoft Dynamics AX - java programist need information

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I have to work with Dynamics 2012 r3 and x++ and I wonder:
what is "::" - its inherit, implementation or what?
why some variables are write like "_vensGroup" - that _ means something or this is just convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer both questions:

:: is a scope dereference to a (static) method (as opposed to . which dereferences a variable, constant or property), usually for the Global scope, but it could be for other similar scopes.  It is reserved.

The underscore prefix is just a naming convention.  It is not part of the language.

Answer (score 4):

:: is a scope. It allows you to use class method (on tables and classes). The point is used to call an object method.
The scope is also used to call values on BaseEnum.

_ is a prefix for parameters. It's a convention. It allows you to recognize local variable and parameters. As parameters are not ment to be changed in a method (they are passed by value), you will always be able to distinguish it from local variables and use them in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your underscore question:
A widely spread convention is to use leading underscores to indicate passed parameters e.g.

```
public void foobar(int _myInt, str _myStr)
{
 ...
}
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa575803.aspx) for the best practice MSDN page describing this convention.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers to your question, `::` is used not only to [call to static table/class methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa584754.aspx), but for other purposes as well, e.g. [call methods in maps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ee330226.aspx) or [reference enums](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa881702.aspx).